# Pentaho Driver Class could not be found, make sure the Generic Database Driver (Jar File) is installed

Tags: jar, pentaho

> Pentaho Driver Class could not be found, make sure the Generic
> Database Driver (Jar File) is installed

Where can I get a generic database driver? Nothing comes up when I do a Google search.

[This](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/8.1/Setup/JDBC_Drivers_Reference) wasn't very helpful. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a generic jdbc driver.

The difference between generic jdbc connection and others is the following:

- for specific connections the user sets the hostname, port, username&password and eventually some other optional fields (such as instance for mssql); In generic connection user must specify the full url and the driver class.
- Specific connections sometimes have some extra intelligence embedded (e.g. getName vs getAlias in MySQL); generic connections don’t do that type of post-processing, whatever comes from the jdbc driver is added to the stream.

So, to set up a generic connection (for sake of argument, let’s say postgres), you need the full postgres jdbc url, the driver class name and credentials. If you need to switch to a different type of database (say Oracle) you can use variables for the driver class name and url. But the driver is still a specific one.

When should you use a generic connection?

- if you need to switch target db types in runtime (though beware that SQL syntax may vary)
- If the database you want to connect to isn’t in the list of supported databases
- If you need a different driver class than the one set up in the specific connection (e.g, MySQL 5.x vs MySQL 8)
- If your connection requires some tweaks to the url from what the default url provided by the jdbc driver says

But if you want to connect to MySQL 8 using a generic connection you still need a MySQL 8 JDBC driver.